# Interface Translation and Internationalization in XUL

Tags: internationalization, firefox-addon, xul

I need to translate an application XUL by two versions English and French. Now all strings in interface on French. What are the tools and Libraries with I can translate the file .XUL or have you an others solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XUL overlays add-ons usually localize with DTD or `.properties` files or both.

The old-but-still-accurate [XUL Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Localization) and the [XUL School tutorial (add-ons)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/The_Essentials_of_an_Extension#Locale) have some examples and descriptions.

Basically it boils down to:

- Declaring one or more [`locale`s in your `chrome.manifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#locale). The browser will then make available the most appropriate locale automatically by the same URI prefix.
- Using DTD in XUL (overlays, windows, dialogs).
- Using [stringbundles (aka. `.properties`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Thunderbird/HowTos/Common_Thunderbird_Extension_Techniques/Access_StringBundle_from_Overlay) for everything else (or even instead of DTDs even for XUL).

#### Example

So for example you might have the following `chrome.manifest` declarations:

```
locale my-addon en-US locale/en-US/
locale my-addon en-GB locale/en-GB/
locale my-addon fr-FR locale/fr-FR/
```

You'd then add `some.dtd` to *all* locales (locale directories):

`locale/en-US/some.dtd`

```
<!ENTITY some.label "Hi">
```

`locale/en-GB/some.dtd`

```
<!ENTITY some.label "Hello">
```

`locale/fr-FR/some.dtd`

```
<!ENTITY some.label "Bonjour">
```

You can then access `some.dtd` by `chrome://my-addon/locale/some.dtd` and the application will automatically select whatever locale best corresponds to the browser and user preferences, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://my-addon/locale/some.dtd">
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
  <popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
    <menuitem label="&some.label;"/>
  </popup>
</overlay>
```

Of course, this does not only work with `.dtd`, but with `.properties` and any other file. You can e.g. add a `flag.png` to all locales, and have the `en-GB` locale be the *Star-Spangled Banner*, the `en-GB` locale be the *Union Jack*, while having the `fr-FR` be *Le Tricolore*.

I demonstrated all of the above in a [full-blown example add-on](https://github.com/nmaier/hello-addon).

#### Add-on SDK

The Add-on SDK uses a similar but different [localization system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/l10n).

#### Testing

ProTip: You can test your add-on locales by changing the value of `general.useragent.locale` via `about:config` and restarting the browser. (There are also add-ons that to this for you). This will even work if the browser is e.g. only English and you switch to e.g. French `fr-FR`/`fr`. Then only the add-ons (incl. your add-on ;) that have a French locale will display french strings while the others will fall back to `en-US` or whatever they support.

Comment: Added example and link to example add-on.